# Excel insert rows (not Add)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I have an Excel '07 Template file for a purchase order. On the template, there's only room for 3 rows worth of items, then the template shows the Total.

So, basically, in the Template it has:
Row 19 - item
Row 20 - item
Row 21 - item
Row 22 - total of the items

Obviously, most purchases will have more than 3 items, though. So how would I *insert* a row between 21 and 22, after printing 3 items out?

Edit; So here's what I have:

```
            xlApp.Workbooks.Open(template, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue); 

int row = 19;
if (poDetailBO1.MoveFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    itemsBO3.FillByPK(poDetailBO1.Style);
                    if (row < 22)
                    {


                        xlApp.Cells[row, 1] = poDetailBO1.LineNo;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 2] = itemsBO3.Factory;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 3] = poDetailBO1.Style;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 4] = itemsBO3.UPC_Code;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 5] = itemsBO3.Item_Description;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 6] = "TARRIFF"; //To be replaced later
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 7] = itemsBO3.Plate_Color;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 8] = itemsBO3.Color;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 9] = poDetailBO1.PrePack;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 10] = itemsBO3.Cost;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 11] = poDetailBO1.Qty;
                        xlApp.Cells[row, 12] = poDetailBO1.Qty * itemsBO3.Cost;

                        row++;
                    }
                    else if (row >= 22)
                    {
                        Excel.Range r = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, misValue], xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, misValue]];
                        r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, misValue);
                        r.Value2 = "GOBBLYDEEGOOK";

                        row++;
                    }
                } while (poDetailBO1.MoveNext());
```

However, my Insert gets inserted into the wrong worksheet, hah. And not where I'd even imagine it to get inserted- Row 2, column 19.

Comment: Why don't you change the template? 3 items per PO seems way too small? What Have you tried?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Derek: The issue is, I don't know how many items might be on a single PO... so no matter how I change the template, I'll need to insert rows either way. Unless you're saying to scrap the "Total" on row 22 and programatically add it myself after I've finished adding items.

Comment: Well, You'd probably want a subtotal for each sheet and a Grand Total on the final sheet, so you will have to change the template I'd imagine, unless that's already incorporated. It just seem's that 3 Items will mean generating far more Invoices.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, I don't see where you are setting your `xlWorksheet` but that would be the first place I'd check to see why your cells are being inserted on the wrong sheet.

Secondly, I don't think your `Excel.Range` object is being set up properly. You could be running into trouble because you're only specifying row numbers in the `WorkSheet.Cells` property and not column names. When I tried that I was getting cells inserted after the used range of cells, not where I wanted. I would be inclined to use the `get_Range()` method of the `Worksheet` object since that usually works in a more predictable manner.

Given all that, depending on whether you want specific cells shifted down, or the entire row, you can use one of the following:

```
// To shift down a set of cells from columns A to F

Excel.Range r = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + row.ToString(), "F" + row.ToString());
r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);

// To shift down all of a row

Excel.Range r = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + row.ToString(), "A" + row.ToString()).EntireRow;
r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see Sid Holland's post until after my lunch break, where a co-worker sent me this code that does basically the same thing as his...

```
    private void CopyRowsDown(int startrow, int count, Excel.Range oRange, Excel.Worksheet oSheet)
    {
        oRange = oSheet.get_Range(String.Format("{0}:{0}", startrow), System.Type.Missing);
        oRange.Select();
        oRange.Copy();
        //oApp.Selection.Copy();

        oRange = oSheet.get_Range(String.Format("{0}:{1}", startrow + 1, startrow + count - 1), System.Type.Missing);
        oRange.Select();
        oRange.Insert(-4121);
        //oApp.Selection.Insert(-4121);

    }
```

Worked perfectly, even when count is 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void CopyRowsDown(_Worksheet worksheet, int startRowIndex, int countToCopy)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < countToCopy; i++)
        {
            var range = worksheet.get_Range(string.Format("{0}:{0}", startRowIndex, Type.Missing));
            range.Select();
            range.Copy();

            range = worksheet.get_Range(string.Format("{0}:{1}", startRowIndex + i, startRowIndex + i, Type.Missing));
            range.Select();
            range.Insert(-4121);
        }
    }
```

works for any count