# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet does not contain a definition for 'InsertRow'

Tags: excel, winforms, c#-4.0

I want to dynamically insert few rows in an excel sheet , but when i tried to use the below code as suggested in many of the answers in stack over flow, but its throwing an error.

```
//Inserting 10 rows into the worksheet starting from 3rd row

 worksheet.Cells.InsertRows(2,10);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet doesnot contain a definition for 'InsertRow' 
and no extension method 'InsertRow' acceping a 1st argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'
```

can any one help me in this...

As per suggestion given below , i tried to update my code

```
    private void Insert_Empty_Rows()
    {
        Excel.Application Excel_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook MyWorkBook = Excel_App.Workbooks.Open(textBox1.Text.ToString(), Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Worksheet MyWorksheet = null;
        MyWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)MyWorkBook.Sheets[(1)];
        Excel.Range Excel_Range;
        Excel_Range = MyWorksheet.UsedRange;
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            ((Excel.Range)MyWorksheet.Rows[2]).Insert();
        }

   }
```

still getting Error "No overload for method 'this' takes '1' arguments  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Insert_Empty_Rows()
    {
        Excel.Application Excel_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook MyWorkBook = Excel_App.Workbooks.Open(textBox1.Text.ToString(), Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Worksheet MyWorksheet = null;
        MyWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)MyWorkBook.Sheets[(1)];
        Excel.Range Excel_Range;
        Excel_Range = MyWorksheet.UsedRange;
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            ((Excel.Range)MyWorksheet.Rows[2,Type.Missing]).Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, Type.Missing);
        }
        SaveFileDialog SaveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Browse to Save Excel Files";
        SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "xls";
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        if (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel_App.DisplayAlerts = false;
            MyWorkBook.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            MyWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            Excel_App.Quit();
        }
        Excel_App.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("SOTP Updated Successfully");

   }
```

if anyone has better solution than the above mentioned one ,Please post it...as this piece of code worked for me .....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, as suggested here for instance:
[Excel insert rows (not Add)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418776/excel-insert-rows-not-add)

```
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            ((Range) worksheet.Rows[2]).Insert();
        }
```

Comment: I tired this code but it's throwing and error "No overload for method 'this' takes '1' arguments "..

Comment: Just tried it here and it works perfectly... what version of the interops are you using?

Comment: i am using  12.0.0.0

Comment: That's the same version that I'm using. You'll have to post your code

Comment: above i posted my code ...i tried to use whatever you suggested still i am getting the error.. i am using excel interops 12.0.0.0

Comment: Are you using an old version of visual studio by any chance? I see you are supplying Type.Missing for all the optional parameters in the .Open method. If so, try supplying the 2 optional parameters for the Insert method as well... `.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, Type.Missing)`

Comment: thanks for reply..yes i am using VS2008...i modified code little bit and it started working for me..

            for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                ((Excel.Range)MyWorksheet.Rows[2,Type.Missing]).Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, Type.Missing);
            }