# How to insert a new row in the specified cell only, of Excel sheet using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

So I have this code:

```
        using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
        ...

        public static void AppendColumnValuesGivenStart(Excel.Worksheet wks, int column, int columnStarts, int totalColumnsInTable, List<ColumnValues> columnValues)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < columnValues.Count; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < totalColumnsInTable; y++)
                {
                    wks.Cells[x + columnStarts, column + y].Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, Type.Missing);
                }
            }
        }
```

It is supposed to insert a new row at the specified position of cell, but in the output it makes a new row that spans all the way to the right and interferes with other tables.

What am I doing wrong and what would be the correct way of inserting a new row in the specified cell?

Comment: Is it a true table or just a range of data that you're wanting to insert into?  Can you provide some screenshots of the before and after?  You're also combining rows with column variables, i.e. `wks.Cells[x + columnStarts, column + y]` the first parameter in the `.Cells` array property is the row index, you have a variable that relates to a column.  I think you may be building a larger area of insert than you think.

Comment: I think @skin is right. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420984/5688800) from another related question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to insert rows into a very selective set of cells in your worksheet.

I have this worksheet with a matrix of data ...

[image: Before]

I then want to insert 5 rows between columns **E** and **J** to give me a result that looks like this ...

[image: After]

To achieve this, there are a few ways to do it.

You can do it via selecting the range specifically and running the insert method ...

```
xlWorksheet.Range["E6:J10"].Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

You can obviously pass in parameters to make it happen as well ...

```
int rowFrom = 6;
int rowTo = 10;

xlWorksheet.Range[$"E{rowFrom}:J{rowTo}"].Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

Or you can do it using cell references ...

```
var cellAddressFrom = ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[6, 5]).Address;
var cellAddressTo = ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[10, 10]).Address;

xlWorksheet.Range[$"{cellAddressFrom}:{cellAddressTo}"].Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

Or more again, cell references using column letters, not numbers ...

```
var cellAddressFrom = ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[6, "E"]).Address;
var cellAddressTo = ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[10, "J"]).Address;

xlWorksheet.Range[$"{cellAddressFrom}:{cellAddressTo}"].Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

Bottom line, you need to get your parameters right and you need to make up a matrix (unless it's a single cell you want to shift down) in order to shift cells down or right.